# CSS ID variations

Tags: css, inheritance, position, generator

Hey, I am guessing that this is probably fairly trivial, but I am having difficulty finding an answer or figuring it out nonetheless.

I'm trying to create a grid of colored squares with arbitrary spacing between them.
This in itself is easy to do, especially because I need only nine squares. But while 
I look at my completed code, I cannot help but feel there is a far more simple and efficient way to accomplish this.

At the moment, I have nine different IDs declared in my css, one for each square.

```
div.container{
    position:relative;
    left:50px;
    top:50px;
    background-color:rgb(45,45,45);
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
}

#square{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:rgb(52,82,222);
    left:20px;
    top:20px;
    height:80px
    width:80px

#square2{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:rgb(58,82,22);
    left:110px;
    top:20px;
    height:80px;
    width:80px;


etc etc etc
```

What I would like to do is find a more efficient way to do this.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the inner squares are `div`s, there are no other `div`s inside your container, and each inner `div` should be the same `width` and `height`, this is what I'd do:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    background: rgb(45,45,45);
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
.container > div {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(52,82,222);
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}

#square1 {
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}
#square2 {
    left: 110px;
    top: 20px;
}
..
```

If you need separate `top` and `left` properties for each `div`, then you have no choice but to use `id`s.

You can avoid having to add a `class` thanks to using `.container > div`, which selects all `div` elements that are direct children of `.container`.

The HTML would look like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="square1"></div>
    <div id="square2"></div>
    ..
</div>
```

Comment: What if i included divs within the squares? Would the `.container > div` affect those as well? Or are they not direct children?

Comment: `.container > div` wouldn't affect those ones. [`>` is the direct child selector.](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/childselector) I've tried very hard to explain it here: [http://jsfiddle.net/Mgk23/](http://jsfiddle.net/Mgk23/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a class for the squares that share a property:

```
.square {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

Is there a specific reason you're absolutely positioning them though? Sounds like a job better suited for floats.

```
div.container {
    width: 240px;
}

.square {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, you beat me to it.

Comment: No reason in particular haha. I suppose its just evidence of my poor CSS skills :P 

What confuses me about your answer however is how do I declare the subsequent squares so that they inherit those constants. I was thinking about this like like OOP but, it doesn't seem like I can approach it in that manner. Thanks for baring with me!

Answer (score 1):

Why not give all of the squares the same class and apply something like

```
.square
{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   zoom: 1;
   *display: inline /* for IE */
}
```

That should make all of the blocks wrap nicely without having to add styles for each individual.